# GMVault Network Access

Tags: gmail

Has anyone ever used GMVault before?  If so, are the messages downloaded from Google passed through any 3rd party server (like GMVault themselves)?  I'd only want the backup connection to be between myself and Google to keep everything secure.

Thanks!

GMVault - http://gmvault.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

GMVault connects directly to Gmail using IMAP, and authenticates using OAuth.  (it doesn't see your password at all)

Answer (score 3):

I confirm. I am the Gmvault developer and there is only a ssl connection between you and the Gmail IMAP server. OAuth is used to connect to the IMAP server but you could also use your password if you wanted to. OAuth is recommended method though.